# Изменилась карта. Как получить изменения?

Tags: java

Есть карта Map. В прекрасный момент несколько её Value могут измениться, ключи конечно же остаются на местах . Мне нужно получить карту которая бы содержала в себе только те пары ключ-значение которые были изменены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал взять keySet() и сделать removeAll() но ключи ведь не меняются, поэтому я получу пустой результат.

Думал получить values() из двух карт и сделать removeAll(), в этом случае я конечно получаю пары которые изменились, но без ключей. Просто голые значения без ключей не годяться.
Как быть?

Comment: Это вы словари так картами называете?

Comment: И не только я .

Comment: Ну просто когда меняете элемент, сохраняйте его ключ куда-нибудь в сет, потом получайте элементы по этим ключам. Сам по себе hashtable такую информацию хранить не должен.

Comment: Ну у вас там своя атмосфера...

Comment: Map меняется очень глубоко в коде. Я могу лишь получить её и  скопировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, можете ли вы использовать сторонние библиотеки, поэтому предлагаю такой вариант:

```
Map<String, Object> a = new HashMap<String, Object>();
a.put("1", "one");
a.put("2", "two");
a.put("3", "three");
Map<String, Object> b = new HashMap<String, Object>(a);
b.put("1", "ein");
System.out.println("before: " + a);
System.out.println("after: " + b);
Map<String, Object> c = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : a.entrySet()) {
  String key = e.getKey();
  if (!e.getValue().equals(b.get(key))) {
    c.put(key, b.get(key));
  }
}
System.out.println("result: " + c);
```

Comment: Хорошо, правда есть минус. Это не будет работать если у меня не переопределен метод equals у объектов values, но мне повезло - я храню в значениях строки. Что вы хотели сказать про сторонниие библиотеки?

Comment: @argamidon Имею ввиду [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Maps). `entriesDiffering() - The entries with the same keys, but differing values.`